# replace number with string using jquery replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

My question is related to this topic [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378300/replacing-a-number-in-a-string-with-jquery)

I would need a jquery replacement function for a number with a string as well, but much finer though.

My php returns a number in this format eg 1.27

Depending on a range this number should be replaced by a certain string that matches a range:

**Example:**

The number 1.27 is in the "active" range of 1.0 and 1.5, so the replacement for this would be the string "active".
The value of 1.51 would be in the "less active" range from 1.5 to 2.0 and the replacement string would be the "less active" string.

Any ideas are much appreciated

Comment: Why not parse and deal with something like an if statement? Although solvable by regex it feels like it's not the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont understand what jQuery has to do with it, but this is pretty simple really...

```
var state = 'Default';
if(value > 1 && value < 1.5)
 state = 'Active';
else if(value < 2)  
 state = 'Less active';
else if(value < 3)
 state = 'Sleeping';
```

You might want to get a good book about programming, this really shouldnt be an issue.

Comment: this is not what he is asking. He wants " UserA - 1.27 : UserB - 1.51" to become " UserA - active : UserB - less active"

Answer (score 3):

Accessing the text in the page can be done using jQuery, but the rest of the code is plain Javascript.

You can use a regular expression to find the number, then use a function that determines what to replace it with, something like this:

```
var element = $('#id');
element.text(element.text().replace(/[\d\.]+/g, function(s){
  var n = parseDouble(s);
  if (n >= 1.0) {
    if (n <= 1.5) return "active";
    if (n <= 2.0) return "less active";
  }
  return s;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot do this with a single line of code. You'd have to do something like the following:

```
$(".number").each(function(){
    var elm = $(this);
    var number = parseFloat(elm.text(), 10);
    if (number >= 1 && number <= 1.5) {
        state = "active";
    } else if (number >= 1.5 && number < 2) {
        state = "less active";
    }
    elm.text(state);
});
```

See the above [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/UDdhL/)

Comment: In my case I need to use a class instead of an id due to to the dom. ATM this does not work of course [link](http://jsfiddle.net/interfacer/k72uc/7/)

Comment: @Christian Updated so that it works with multiple elements (classes)